# Google StreetView/Map API

Tags: android, google-maps, google-street-view

Is their any way to get nearby streetviews coordinates with respect to a particular location (coordinates)

Here, I am using this thing, but it is returning wrong information 
.
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=13.0602543,77.6471364&radius=1000&type=streetview&sensor=true&key={API_KEY}

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the [Street View Image Metadata](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/metadata) endpoint in order to get nearest available street view panorama.

In your case you can run the following request

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview/metadata?location=13.0602543%2C77.6471364&radius=1000&source=default&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

This request returns the following response

```
{
    "copyright":"© Prashant Dubey",
    "date":"2018-09",
    "location":{
        "lat":13.0602702,
        "lng":77.6470768
    },
    "pano_id":
      "CAoSK0FGMVFpcFBLMTdMM25RWEMxWEk4TmJWZkdmbzZpdlZJdWZ0aHhmbFlyR2s.",
    "status":"OK"
}
```

So you have here both the location and pano ID.

I hope this helps!

Comment: hey bro, This is returning only one streetview. I need all the streetviews.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not possible. Google doesn't provide any endpoint to get all streetviews. You can find only the nearest one.

Comment: Is there any option or logic to find all nearest streetviews?